# How do I edit the below jQuery to return the hover logo change to original state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

first post here. My code is below. What I have here is basically a navigation menu (#nav), and a logo (#logo). When hovering over the #nav elements, I've used data-href and an image link to swap the #logo image when hovering over different navigation items. For instance hover over 'Blue' the logo goes to the blue image. Upon hovering OFF though, the code below just sticks at the last image viewed. Is there a way to return it to the original state when hovering off?

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li data-href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo-marketing.png" class="nav1"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/marketing">Marketing</a></li>
    <li data-href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo-consultancy.png" class="nav2"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/consultancy">Consultancy</a></li>
    <li data-href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo-project-management.png" class="nav3"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/project-management">Project Management</a></li>
    <li data-href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo-production-engineering.png" class="nav4"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/production-engineering">Production & Engineering</a></li>
    <li data-href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo-innovation.png" class="nav5"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/innovation">Innovation</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var nav = $('#nav')[0];
var output = $('#logo')[0];

$(nav).on('hover', 'li', function() {
    $(this).stop().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    var url = $(this).stop().data('href');
    $(logo).html('<img src="' + url + '">');
});
});
```

Comment: have u missed the #nav by mistake? $('#nav').on('hover', 'li', function() {

Comment: try to replace nav with "#nav" and remove var nav = $('#nav')[0], var output is not used and you have undefined logo variable (should logo be replaced by output?)

Comment: Your php is irrelevant to the jQuery. We need to see the HTML, not the server-side script.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `#logo` is a `div`? If so, use a `data` attribute to set it's default image url, then revert to that on mouseout:

```
<div id="logo" data-defaultimg="myimg.jpg"><img /></div>
```

```javascript
$(function(){
    var $nav = $('#nav');
    var $logo = $('#logo');

    $nav.on('hover', 'li', function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
            var url = $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected").data("href");
            $logo.html('<img src="' + url + '">');
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected"); 
            $logo.html('<img src="' + $logo.data("defaultimg") + '">');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Rory, thanks for your answer. It kinda works but doesn't quite. The basic default image works, but now for some reason the images aren't changing upon hover over. The #logo was infact a <h1> tag but for testing purposes I've switched to <div>. Here's the logo code (now):     <div id="logo" data-defaultimg="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.png"><img />
      <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="txt-img">Logo</a>
     </div>

Answer (score 0):

No jquery needed if I'm understanding correctly what you are after.

```
<ul id="logo_list">
  <li class="logo_item">
     <div class="logo_default"> put stuff as if item is not hovered </div>
     <div class="logo_hovered"> put stuff as if item is hovered </div>
  </li>
</ul>

.logo_hovered
{
   display:none;
}

.logo_item:hover .logo_default
{
  display:none;
}

.logo_item:hover .logo_hovered
{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the comment. It is similar to what you're describing here but the #logo isn't nested within the list, so I thought it'd be easier to target with jQuery. Though I suppose I could position absolute the two inner <div> tags if needed. Thank you.